# How to display numbers like 10,000.42 using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, decimal-number

I would like to do something like `\SI{10,000.42}{\m}` using siunitx. But using two potential decimal markers always results in the following error message:

```
Package siunitx Error: Duplicate decimal marker token '.' in input.
```

So far I couldn't find any settings in the manual to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `input-decimal-markers` and `input-ignore` correctly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers = ., input-ignore ={,}}
\begin{document}
\SI{10,000.42}{\metre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `input-ignore` was missing in my settings.